# VBA Access table check if range in recordset has a checkbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to setup a way to check if, in a table, a checkbox is checked for each "PackNum" in the table.
So for example if "PackNum" 123456 has at least one checkbox then it's okay. but if "PackNum" 654321 doesn't have any check boxes I want to throw up a message.

| PackNum | Offer | Select |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | DA |  |
| 123456 | DD | x |
| 123456 | DC | x |
| 645321 | CC |  |
| 645321 | CD |  |
| 645321 | CF |  |

I've been tinkering with the following code but not having much luck.

```
Private Sub Okay_Button_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim strPack As String


Checked = False
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblMtemp")
strPack = rs2.Fields("PackNum").Value

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Data Validation check that there is at least one box checks for each packnumber
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Not (rs2.EOF And rs2.BOF) Then
    rs2.MoveFirst
Do Until rs2.EOF = True

    If IsNull(DLookup("ID", "tblMtemp", rs2.Fields("Select") = True And rs2.Fields("PackNum") = " & strPack & ")) Then
    MsgBox "Box is Checked"
    Else
    MsgBox "Box is not Checked"
    End If
rs2.MoveNext
Loop
End If

End Sub
```

This keeps assuming everything is wrong. I think this could be cause I'm using Access? I'm not sure. I'm not as familiar with the syntax for building something like this.

### Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: No, it's not because using Access, it's because code is bad. Need to loop through records, not controls. Or use DCount() domain aggregate function. Where is rs2 declared and set? What event is code in? When do you want message to trigger - when user enters record?

Comment: @June7 okay wow... so as I said I'm not sure of the syntax I'm not sure how this kind of thing works. Still learning as I go. the rs2 is my recordset pulling from a table. It's declared early on. Looping through records was my first thought but I couldn't figure out how to deal with the logic on looking at all offers under the same pack number to make sure at least one was checked. I'd like my warning to trigger if there is a packnum that doesn't have any offers selected. But it's okay if only 1 is selected. I'll update my code to my original loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is named `MyTable` and your table's primary key field is `TableID` then:

```
IsNULL(DLookup("TableID","MyTable","Select=TRUE AND PackNum=123456"))
```

returns `FALSE` if `"PackNum" 123456 has at least one checkbox`.

If you want to use that in a loop where `123456` is a variable:

```
IsNULL(DLookup("TableID","MyTable","Select=TRUE AND PackNum=" & PackNumVariable ))
```

and if `PackNum` is a text and not a number type:

```
IsNULL(DLookup("TableID","MyTable","Select=TRUE AND PackNum='" & PackNumVariable & "'"))
```

Comment: I added a string to grab the records packnumber so it's now `IsNull (DLookup("ID", "tblMtemp", "Select" = TRUE AND PackNum = '" & strPack & "'"))` I'm getting a Type Mismatch which is strange. Packnum is a number type.

Comment: Okay I figured out the problem with the type mismatch. Still having issues with it recognizing what I want. Code is updated in OP post. Any thoughts why it's not recognizing the difference between checked and not checked?

Comment: You are neither using `DLookup` correctly nor is your loop appropriate. You have to loop through the potential values of `PackNum` and use `DLookup` as I posted, not just loop through all your records.